# Can OpenXML be used in VB6

Tags: excel, vb6, openxml

I've had great success with using OpenXML for creating and modifying excel spreadsheets in both C#.Net and VB.Net.  We now have a need to modify a spreadsheet in VB6.  Will OpenXML integrate with VB6?  Does anyone have an example project showing how to set it up?

Comment: you can write xml in vb6 so I would have to say... yes. Why you feel you have to use VB6? That's the real question. Create a c# library and then make it into a signed TLB. You can then reference it in your VB6 app.